# iTextPDF 5.5.0 BouncyCastle dependency issue

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I'm trying to extract digital signature data from signed PDF using iTextPDF in Java. My code is:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);
AcroFields af = reader.getAcroFields();
ArrayList<String> names = af.getSignatureNames();
if(names == null || names.isEmpty()) return null;
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(null, null);
    ArrayList<Map<QName, Serializable>> aspects = new ArrayList<Map<QName, Serializable>>();
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println("Signature name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Signature covers whole document: " + af.signatureCoversWholeDocument(name));
        System.out.println("Document revision: " + af.getRevision(name) + " of " + af.getTotalRevisions());

        PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);
        X509Certificate certificate = pk.getSigningCertificate();

        Map<QName, Serializable> aspectSignatureProperties = new HashMap<QName, Serializable>(); 
        aspectSignatureProperties.put(SignModel.PROP_CERTIFICATE_PRINCIPAL, certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().toString());
        aspectSignatureProperties.put(SignModel.PROP_CERTIFICATE_SERIAL_NUMBER, certificate.getSerialNumber().toString());
        aspectSignatureProperties.put(SignModel.PROP_CERTIFICATE_NOT_AFTER, certificate.getNotAfter());
        aspectSignatureProperties.put(SignModel.PROP_CERTIFICATE_ISSUER, certificate.getIssuerX500Principal().toString());   
        aspects.add(aspectSignatureProperties);
    }
```

However, at `PdfPKCS7 pk = af.verifySignature(name);` i get this Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1ObjectIdentifier
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2349)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields.verifySignature(AcroFields.java:2302)
at es.keensoft.alfresco.behaviour.CustomBehaviour.getDigitalSignatures(CustomBehaviour.java:133)
at es.keensoft.alfresco.behaviour.CustomBehaviour.onCreateNode(CustomBehaviour.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour$JavaMethodInvocationHandler.invoke(JavaBehaviour.java:174)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy54.onCreateNode(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.alfresco.repo.policy.TransactionBehaviourQueue.execute(TransactionBehaviourQueue.java:245)
... 41 more
```

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 56 more`

I tried to include BouncyCastle dependencies but then I get:

> Signer information does not match

Any ideas?
Thanks

EDIT:

I'm using Maven with these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Comment: What version of BouncyCastle are you using? If you use Maven, run this command and add the output to your question: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose`

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse  Done. Sorry, I didn't get that earlier.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse anything?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I added the bouncycastle tag to your question because it's a BouncyCastle error.

Comment: Actually this looks like you have different Jars containing classes in the `org.bouncycastle.asn1` package. Most likely multiple BouncyCastle jars for different versions. More generally your code base or some other library you have in your classpath brings with it an extra copy of some BouncyCastle classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.50</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>                    
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Dependencies are not clearly declared by iText in Maven.

As other users claim in the answers, 1.49 is working fine with 5.5.0. First MAVEN versions of iText where not so clear managing dependencies (even Bruno Lowagie talked about that).

The problem seems to be that existent 1.45 artifacts are interfering with the execution. In that case, following libraries combination will work.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.45</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.45</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>                    
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Same thing happens: `java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package`. :(

Comment: That won't work, BC 1.50 isn't compatible with iText 5.5.x. You really need 1.49.

Comment: _Dependencies are not clearly declared by iText in Maven._ That's not true either, if you look at the POM: https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/5.5.0/itext/pom.xml

Comment: It looks that it works also with BC 1.49. Please take a look at https://github.com/angelborroy-ks/signature-position

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are deploying to a environment who already have that BC libraries (bcmail-jdk15-1.45.jar, bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar). In that case, you need to downgrade to text 5.0.6 in order to use that BC versions.